# Reserving a subdomain on cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

Once I push an app on cloudfoundry, and assign it a name, I can access it via appname.cloudfoundry.com

Will that app name only stay reserved while the app is running ?

I have seen a procedure to re-deploy an app, and switch urls, by assigning 2 urls to the same app, and then switching them later..

Is that the only way to "reserve" a appname ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering that too and after some research I couldn't find any other way to just reserve subdomains. So you have to assign them with an application like you did.

Cloudfoundry is still in development and such things might be possible later.

Comment: This is correct. Subdomains cannot be reserved on CloudFoundry.com without mapping it to an app. However, it doesn't matter if the app is running or not; the subdomain stays mapped to it.

Comment: @GlennOppegard thanks for that input. Does Cloudfoundry support reserving subdomains in the future?

Comment: I don't believe so, since we'd like to discourage "squatting" of subdomains.